# Show a 'no programming questions' banner to users without at least 1 well-received question

Tags: feature-request, scope, meta

Downvoting and closing programming questions that are asked here on Meta, is getting old.

Can you add a big banner above the *Title* field to make it clear that programming questions must not be posted here, and display it to users who don't have at least 1 well-received question here? (Inspired by the [Curious](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/90/curious) badge.)

You could also add an additional check to only show it when a code block is used, but you can't really trust these users to properly format their post either.

Comment: I'm not sure if that will help. I mean they don't even see the different logo with different colors and all the tooltips on the ask page which have nothing to do with programming. So how should another text box help? </half-way-sarcastic>

Comment: @Rizier123 Hopefully, such a banner would be more in-your-face than the guidelines in the side bar.

Comment: Does it happen so often? There was one today of course, but I don't have the idea myself that it is happening daily

Comment: @Gimby If you don't see them during the first few minutes they are up, you won't notice. They gather downvotes and close votes rather quickly, so they drop off the front page. The more time you spend here, the more often you'll see these questions.

Comment: @stijn ah, I need to lurk even harder then :) Upvote it is.

Comment: Actually, check out this feature request: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/335240/question-submission-checklist-to-help-improve-quality . This proposes an *interactive* blocking banner where you have to make decisions. That instantly made me think of this feature request. It seems just a step better than only showing a nagging message that may become invisible to people on a mission.

Comment: ... How about propagating all of our Meta votes to the Real World SO? *That'll teach 'em.*

Comment: According to the mods, the *vast* majority of these posts are from question banned users, not people that just got lost and didn't realize they were on meta, so even if they read such a warning message(which is unlikely enough) they're the type of people that would ignore it and post the question anyway, even knowing this isn't the right place to post it.

Comment: @Servy if that's the case, then I agree a banner wouldn't help much. I've asked Shog if he has time to give us some numbers.

Comment: "Most" is probably inaccurate, @Stijn. I'd guess closer to 1/4.

Comment: @Rizier123: Seriously? You're considering *logo colors and tooltips* to be a clear indication of the topic of the site? I can't even find the tooltips you're talking about, unless you're referring to the ones that explain the editor buttons and say things like "Code Sample `<pre> <code>` Ctrl+K".

Comment: I didn't see the "on Meta" part initially and was incredibly confused as to why there seemed to be so much support for stopping programming questions on SO. I kept thinking, "I thought that was the point?" Makes a lot more sense with those two words in.