# Question submission checklist to help improve quality

Tags: feature-request, questions, new-users

As a constant user of SO, questions from new users with 1 reputation that are very low quality plague the entire site. Some of these are better than others, and others are just "do my job for me" questions.

The [feature-request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/feature-request): to have a sort of checklist when the **new user** submits a question on Stack Overflow. So, the checklist would ask people about their questions, and make them fix it to submit the question to the site. It would *hopefully* improve question quality on the site. Here is a quick mockup of what I mean (includes excerpts from the help centre).

[image: Mockup of checklist]
*You may need to zoom in to read the text*

This could be appropriated across SE, and there could be multiple checklists (with the mockup showing an "unexpected behaviour" checklist).

EDIT (suggested by @Hayt): Allow the person to preview the question before submitting it, after they have completed the checklist.

EDIT 2 (suggested by @Paulie_D): The related questions section next to my post has some similar questions which mention things like checklists. The difference is that this post is an official feature request.

Comment: If you review the Related questions on the right ---->, you'll see that this has come up **several** times before.

Comment: Something like a preview or so would also be nice again. A lot of times things are badly formatted and look like they never looked ad the preview.

Comment: @Paulie_D Definitely related, although this is an official feature request.

Comment: @Hayt Indeed, added as an edit

Comment: This is better than other suggestions I've seen. Would be nice to do a little machine learning here. Yes, I intentionally used a buzzword for a dilbert like effect.

Comment: [This discussion](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326868/424903) has many really good design ideas to improve the "ask a question" feature. This is another good one for the list. I hesitate to say: a really good one.

Comment: @techydesigner No he who hesitates is at best late, but not lost.

Comment: We've been discussing ways to improve the /ask page. This is an interesting idea that I'll show the rest of the team working on the revamp.

Comment: some related reading: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260039/could-some-bad-questions-be-avoided-with-additional-prompting and http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266361/the-good-the-bad-the-ugly